# How to run eclipse with a specific jdk (instead of JDK_HOME)

Tags: eclipse

How can I run Eclipse with a specific JDK instead of the one pointing to by JDK_HOME on Linux?

I read this
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher#Finding_a_VM.2C_Using_JNI_Invocation_or_Executing_Java

And I have put

```
-vm /home/michael/Programs/jdk1.7.0_03/bin
```

in my eclipse.ini file.

But when I run Eclipse, it still uses the JDK in my JDK_HOME. I check that via 'About Eclipse' and in configuration details tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My `eclipse.ini` entry looks like:

```
-vm  
C:/P/Java/jdk_1_7_0_02/bin/javaw.exe
```

Comment: More detailed answers are in https://stackoverflow.com/q/23174265/384674 and I'd recommend this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50562620/384674 where is link to `eclipse.ini` documentation in comment.