# How to specify jdk path in eclipse.ini on windows 8 when path contains space

Tags: java, eclipse

This doesn't work `-vm %JAVA_HOME%/bin/javaw.exe`

How can I replace `%JAVA_HOME%` with full path on Windows 8 when path contains space (*"Program Files"* directory)

Comment: http://www.onkarjoshi.com/blog/84/configuring-eclipse-to-use-a-jdk-at-a-location-with-spaces-in-it/

You can obtain path without spaces with windows command line.

Comment: Why do you need to specify -vm argument. Leave ini file alone and set JAVA_HOME environment variable instead.

Comment: Have you tried `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe` with backward slash? Have your set the `JAVA_HOME` enviroment system property?

Comment: @Braj yes I did set the environment variable in computer advanced properties

Comment: Look at my answer you don't need to set the environment variable. Its working fine for me.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Have you tried it. Don't put everything in single line.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\bin\javaw.exe
```

Need to put the folder that contains the javaw or java executable. Under Ubuntu 18 with eclipse 4.7.1 I was able to get it to run with:

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133
-vmargs
-Xmx2G
-Xms200m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
```

If it doesn't work then please confirm you have added above lines before `-vmargs` in `eclipse.ini`.

Comment: By the way it's eclipse I downloaded from android dev site

Comment: I know this topic is old, but I had the same problem, in which none of the solutions mentioned here had worked - but I *DID* eventually solve it.

First, note that using the Windows Environment Variable "JAVA_HOME" is the preferred method, but -vm will work as well.

The cause / solution was: I was using Eclipse 64-bit version, but pointing to a 32-bit JRE - after installing, then pointing to, the 64-bit JRE, all worked well. Thought I'd share this.

Comment: Thanks NYCBilly. It is very important to check the version (32-bit or 64 bit).

Comment: use forward slashes in the eclipse.ini, in which case (even on windows) you do not have to escape the path ie C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_07/bin

Comment: After added the above two lines, it worked. My java home configured as 1.6 for other purposes but i wanted to use eclipse neon IDE, so about trick worked.

Comment: simply best answer.

Answer (score 59):

Add the entry of vm above the vm args else it will not work..!
i.e    `

```
    -vm
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\javaw.exe
    --launcher.appendVmargs
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
    -Xms40m
    -Xmx512m
```

Comment: This works, the order of args are importan (i.e: if add the -vm to the end of the file)

Comment: Also, make sure that path is in next line of -vm,and above --launcher.appendVmargs otherwise it won't work. -vm and path space separated , it creates issue.

Comment: @EnriqueSanMartín you are wrong, `-vm` cannot be at the end, it has to be before `-vmargs` !

Answer (score 31):

## tl;dr

The `-vm` option must occur after the other Eclipse-specific options (such as `-product`, `--launcher.*`, etc), but before the `-vmargs` option, since everything after `-vmargs` is passed directly to the JVM.
Add the `-vm` option on its own line and the path to your JDK **executable** on the following line; e.g.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\
```

## Details

### Notes

- The path is on a new line below the `-vm` option
- There is no need to escape any characters or use slashes (back-slashes are fine)
- The path points to the `bin` directory, not to `javaw.exe`

### Gotcha JAVA_HOME

When you don't specify a virtual machine in your `eclipse.ini` file, you may think that the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is used, but this is not the case!
From [FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse#Find_the_JVM](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM)

> Eclipse DOES NOT consult the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Instead the Windows search path will be scanned.

**Recommendation**
You may think it is a good idea to use the search path, because it is flexible.
While this is true, it also has the downside that the search path may be altered by installing or updating programs.
Thus, I recommend to use the explicit setting in the `eclipse.ini` file.

### Finding a VM

The reason why you should specify the `bin` directory and not the `javaw.exe` (as proposed by many other answers), is that the launcher can then dynamically choose which is the best way to start the JVM. See [details of the launcher process](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher#Finding_a_VM.2C_Using_JNI_Invocation_or_Executing_Java) for all details:

> We look in that directory for: (1) a default.ee file, (2) a java launcher or (3) the jvm shared library.

### Verfication

You can verify which VM is used by your running eclipse instance in the *Configuration* dialogue.
In eclipse Oxygen go to *Help* - *About Eclipse* - *Installation Details* - *Configuration*

You will see which VM path eclipse has chosen, e.g.:

```
eclipse.vm=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Comment: tl;dr is quite incorrect. `-vm` should **not** be at the top of your `eclipse.ini` file. Per [this documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini), "The -vm option must occur after the other Eclipse-specific options (such as -product, --launcher.*, etc), but before the -vmargs option, since everything after -vmargs is passed directly to the JVM." Also has to point to executable, not directory.

Comment: Edited answer per above comment.

Comment: @JeffAxelrod thanks for the edit - I was not aware of that

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same issue but was unable to solve, until I try this:

1. Please make sure you put `-vm`
2. Then press `Enter`
3. And then paste `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\bin\javaw.exe`

Comment: Thank you! Who'd have thunk "press ENTER is important"!? I kept adding -vm <path> to the ini file, it couldn't find it. Once I inserted a newline, it worked!! It didn't matter if we specified javaw.exe or not.

Answer (score 7):

if you are using mac, proceed with following steps:

1. Move to following directory:

   ```
   /sts-bundle/STS.app/Contents/Eclipse
   ```
2. Add the java home explicitly in STS.ini file:

   ```
   -vm
   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
   -vmargs
   ```

Make sure **not to add** all the statements in single line

Answer (score 4):

Solution in:[How do I set the eclipse.ini -vm option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905611/how-do-i-set-the-eclipse-ini-vm-option)

-vm
C:\\bin

```
 -vm
C:\<java_path>\bin
```

Must be the first thing in eclipse.ini

Comment: you don't have to specify the javaw.exe, give the path till bin and it will find javaw.exe in the folder.

Answer (score 4):

All above answers didn't work for me. My Eclipse mars is x64 but I need to set registry dll to x86 for another software.

At the end I put -vm argument at the end of shortcut and this did the trick.

`D:\mars\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll"`

According to [this doc](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example) jvm.dll also work for some cases.

Comment: This one works for me for spring tool suite eclipse ..Thanks

Comment: Nothing else worked because the VM argument in the shortcut gets picked up first. I removed `-vm` in my shortcut then `-vm` was picked up from `SpringToolSuite4.ini`.

Answer (score 2):

Even if your %JAVA_HOME% contains spaces, you can directly put entire string over there.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin
```

Also, you don't have to specify javaw.exe in the path, just mention it till bin it will find javaw.exe in bin folder by itself.
Just keep one thing in mind that the jdk version you provide should match with the eclipse version you are using.

If you are using a 64 bit java then download 64 bit Eclipse.
If you are using a 32 bit java then download 32 bit Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Windows-vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\**jre**\bin\javaw.exe"

Answer (score 1):

I have Windows 8.1 and my JDK under "Program Files" as well. What worked for me was replacing the name of the folder by the 8-digit internal MS-DOS name.

```
-vm
C:/PROGRA~1/Java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/javaw.exe
```

I realized what was going on after running this in cmd.exe

```
CD \
DIR P* /X
```

It returned...

```
<DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
<DIR>          PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
```

So we can find out how to use a path containing spaces

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the space with back slash..  Like

C:\program\folder\ \name\java\jdk\bin

Answer (score 0):

Go to C drive root in cmd
Type dir /x
This will list down the directories name with ~.use that instead of Program Files in your jdk path

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes spaces in path create a problem.
You can add e.g.
-vm
C:\progra~1\Java\jre1.8.0_112\bin\javaw.exe

Answer (score -3):

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: please try to provide some explanation along with the answer for better understanding

Answer (score -10):

Reinstall java and choose a destination folder without a space