# I installed JRE and JDK 8, but in Eclipse it shows Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0 JDK. What to do?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I've been having

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

So I looked it up, and then updated both my JRE and JDK to 8th version.

But above the console, it displays:

> System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0 JDK ....

How do I make my Eclipse run in 8th version of JDK and JRE?
And do I need to change anything in my projects after upgrading?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set your JAVA_HOME correctly.

Comment: JAVA_HOME can also be set in eclipse.ini :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174265/how-to-specify-jdk-path-in-eclipse-ini-on-windows-8-when-path-contains-space

Comment: Eclipse start script can configurations can be modified using eclipse.ini -vm option 
[Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174265/how-to-specify-jdk-path-in-eclipse-ini-on-windows-8-when-path-contains-space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse:

- Select pull-down menu: Windows > Preferences
- On left, select Java > Installed JREs

  - Click "Add..." and browse to your JDK/JRE folder
  - Rename if desired, e.g. change "jdk1.8.0_51" to "jdk1.8"
  - Repeat if you want access to more JDK/JRE versions in Eclipse workspace
  - Check the JRE you want to be the *default* for your projects
- On left, select Java > Compiler

  - Set compliance level to match the default JRE

Note: If your projects don't use the workspace default, then you need to update the project Properties.

---

Eclipse *itself* is running with the default Java, i.e. the java on your `PATH`. If you want Eclipse to run using a different JDK/JRE, you need to edit the `eclipse.ini` file. See the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174265/how-to-specify-jdk-path-in-eclipse-ini-on-windows-8-when-path-contains-space) provided by Tarun Gupta.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you have to change the Java location like below steps

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check for:

1) Proper java environment variable setup.
2) Right click on Project name in Project Explorer in Eclipse. 
    Click on `Build Path` -> `Configure Build Path`.
    Check for proper path for *Java Build Path*.
Also check whether the latest version of Java is     selected in `Java Compiler` -> `Compiler Compliance Level`.
3) Check from command line which Java is installed by typing `java -version` or `java`. 
(Sometimes Java installed from command line in Linux systems installs old versions)