# Failed to load JNI shared library while running STS tool

Tags: java, android, spring-tool-suite

I am getting error while running the STS (Spring Tools Suits) tool for Java i.e.

> Failed To Load The JNI Shared Library  "path\jvm.dll"

What should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: I guess you are on Windows and it looks like the launcher couldn't find the JDK. Can you try to specify the exact JDK that STS should use by setting it in the STS.ini, like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174265/how-to-specify-jdk-path-in-eclipse-ini-on-windows-8-when-path-contains-space

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this question/answer: [Failed to load the JNI shared Library (JDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk)

Quick Summary: I am using 64-bit Windows 10, multiple Java JDK's installed, apparently one was 32-bit Java, and I had installed STS 32-bit. I upgraded to the latest Java 1.8u161 64-bit and that is when my STS had this same issue. The solution was installing the 64-bit version of STS and things are running fine -- I just wish I had exported my update sites.