# Unable to run Eclipse Neon.3 with Java 10

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just downloaded Elicpse Neon 3. When running it, it asked for inputting of workspace, which I point it to a new preferred location. Then after hitting OK, it shows me an error message box

`An error has occured. See the log file C:\test\.metadata\.log`

I am aware there has been many questions been asked in Stackoverflow, but I have tried most of the solutions, which include deleteing the metadata, but I am still not able to get Eclipse running.

My environment:

- Java JDK 10.0.2
- Java JRE 10.0.2

java version screenshot here

[image]

I have also include C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin and C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.2\bin into the environment variable path. Hope to have advice.

The error from .log is as below

```
!SESSION 2020-07-03 10:49:40.224 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
java.version=10.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_MY
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-07-03 10:58:20.742
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2020-07-03 10:58:20.775
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of C:\test\.metadata\.log?  That might give more clues about the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: @BrentWordenI I have posted the error message below. Thanks

Comment: @BrentWorden Sorry, I have pasted the log content in my question for your reference.

Comment: Java 8 is the only version of Java you can use with Neon.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for your suggestion which I shall try out. Just wondering whether the issue I encounter is related to the versioning ? It seems so "innocent" and did not exhibit any version-related issue. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Java 9 and later have the new Java module system which Eclipse Neon does not understand and will not work with.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the sharing. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Java 10 didn't exist when Neon.3 was released in early 2017; even Java 9 was still six months away.

Get the current Eclipse release, 2020-06, instead: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ .

Comment: @niltind, I suppose it's versioning issue then. I am actually at the crossroad of between using Eclipse 2020 and Eclipse Neon .3 because with 2020, I am having trouble running the AVD emulators for API 26  and above. However, I can get it to run on Eclipse Neon .3. ANyway, let me think about it and get back to you.

Comment: You can also try updating the eclipse ini file pointing it to JDK version on your machine.

Comment: @MohsinKhan I may need you kind assistance to guide me on how to add the line that points to the JDK version. Thanks.

Comment: You add following line
 -vm  
C:\you path\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin
you can also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174265/how-to-specify-jdk-path-in-eclipse-ini-on-windows-8-when-path-contains-space