# Could not initialize class org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructureSerializer -Maven Configuration Problem Any solution?

Tags: eclipse, maven, servlets

When I am creating a Maven project I am getting this error in `pom.xml`

> Could not initialize class
> org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructureSerializer
> -Maven Configuration Problem
>
> web.xml is missing and <failOnMissingWebXml> is set to true.

Comment: Mostly encounter in during source setup, updated "maven-war-plugin" can solve it.

Answer (score 98):

It might because the version of `maven-war-plugin` is too old in your project.

Try to add below code in your `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It fixes the error I was having !

Comment: Is there a solution without upgrading maven-war-plugin ? ( the plugin is in team's super pom ) @buzz-dee

Answer (score 18):

```
<build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Note: you should have the build tag
place everything inside build tag then, it will not throw error

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This fixed my problem. I had a lower version  (2.2) in my pom. When I updated that to 3.3.1, it got fixed.

Answer (score 13):

If you are getting this error within Eclipse (my Eclipse version was `Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0), Build id: 20210910-1417` at the time of writing) and you recently tried to move to JDK 17, it appears Eclipse is not compatible with JDK 17. It requires at least JDK 11. I reverted back to Java 11.0.12 and the error has gone away.

Comment: can you tell me more about it? my ppm.xml is:
`
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myclass</groupId>
  <artifactId>Elearning</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Elearning Website</name>
</project>
`

Comment: My pom.xml file for most of my projects starts off nearly the same: 
`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>my-artifact-id</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Incredible GUI</name>` however, I have a parent pom.xml file with the groupId tag (that uses pom packaging).

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Windows 10 and Eclipse Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0) Build id: 20220310-1457

My project uses JDK8, but newer versions of Eclipse require at least JDK11.
I configure this using Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs
as shown in the screenshot:
[image]

Maven from windows cmd shell works fine: `mvn clean package`

But, Eclipse gives an error on my pom.xml: `Could not initialize class org.apache.maven.plugins.war.util.WebappStructureSerializer`

For reference, Eclipse gave some other error messages while I was attempting to fix the issue, such as this one: `Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module`

This error seems to be some compatibility issue with maven-war-plugin and the JDK17 that eclipse runs under. It's probably due to the 'module' permissions.

Using these helpful answers, I was able to find a workaround: 
@Capricorn1 https://stackoverflow.com/a/69544567/4505142 
@SreedharGS https://stackoverflow.com/a/29383652/4505142

I downloaded OpenJDK11 from: https://adoptium.net/

Updated eclipse.ini to use JDK11 instead of JDK17:

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Users\User1\OpenJDK11\jdk-11.0.15+10\bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

For reference, here's the original eclipse.ini JDK17 path:

```
-vm
plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.2.v20220201-1208/jre/bin
```

Using JDK11 to run Eclipse, eliminated the pom.xml error "Could not initialize class org.apache.maven.plugins.war.util.WebappStructureSerializer"

For reference, here are the relevant snippets of my pom.xml:

```xml
    <properties>
        <spring-boot.version>1.5.13.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.18.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-war-plugin.version>3.0.0</maven-war-plugin.version>     
    </properties>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>**/application-*.properties</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-war</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-info</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: I'd like to know what if i need a higher version of Tomcat which is not available in Eclipse ? If I were to configure it via the example in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsfRSrDgBWI, will it be possible to remove the Tomcat later to make it flexible for deployment in other kinds of servers ?

Answer (score 2):

In Pom.xml, need to add the below snippet, and please find image attachment

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>


</build>
```

- After update Maven Project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HArI.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Please use the below code snip:**

```
 <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Please refer [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/plugin-info.html)

Answer (score 0):

I updated Eclipse and Set the Compiler and JDK to 17.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the plugin to your maven project, by adding this in your pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</plugin>
```

After that: Right click -> Maven -> Update Project

Answer (score -3):

I have the same problem as this when I create a maven project. So I got a solution for this just adding this plug into your pom.xml:

```
<plugin> 
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

If you already have it, then you should upgrade its version.